# How to submit form in custom wp plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a wp plugin to show a list from table,which can be edited and
deleted .
I am succeed in showing a list in plugin.but not getting how to update .

can any one tell me what will be the path in form action,
,and after form get submited  where does it goes ie on which page.
on which page should i write update query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place all your form handlers on the same page, but be sure to place them before any output. Like this:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['my-form-submit'])) : // check if form is submitted
/*
Here goes update process etc
*/
endif;
get_header();
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="POST">
/* Here come form fields */
<input type="submit" name="my-form-submit" value="Update" />
</form>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: thanks @Alhana , i was googling many site for this solution , but was unable to get the required solution .your answer is very helpful to beginner like me